# Calculation of probability for the game

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

There is a game on which I am working now and I need to balance it.

There are N=10 dices and K=3 attempts for throw them simultaneously.
If a 6 comes up on any die, then this die is transferred to the winning dice pool, and the number of attempts becomes 3 again.
The game continues either until the dice run out or until the attempts run out.

For example:

1. N=10, K=3, the player rolled 0 dices with the number 6. Next turn.
2. N=10, K=2, the player rolled 6 dices with the number 6. Next turn.
3. N=4, K=3, the player rolled 0 dices with the number 6. Next turn.
4. N=4, K=2, the player rolled 0 dices with the number 6. Next turn.
5. N=4, K=1, the player rolled 0 dices with the number 6. Game is over, there are 6 dices in the winning pool.

Questions:

1. What is the average number of dice in the winning pool? What will be the standard deviation?
2. What is the probability that there are exactly n dice in the winning pool, where n is in [0..N]?
3. How to generalize the solution for an arbitrary number of dice (N), an arbitrary number of attempts (K), and an arbitrary probability (p) of rolling 6 (not necessarily 1/6)?

Thank you in advance for your helping!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I started solving this task in Excel, but I even can't image how to start. I want to make a table, where I can edit a probability, set attempts count and count of dices to balancing "fun" from mini-game.

Comment: @loki Suppose you get no 6s on your first attempt, and then one 6 on your second attempt. How many attempts do you have left? (From the description in the original post, seems like it could be 2 or 3.)

Comment: @paw88789 I understood my mistake so I have added an example.

Comment: You need to cut this complex game in small exercices. Question 1: I throw $n$ dice, what is the probability to have $0$ (resp. $1$. $2$, ... $n$ ) times the number 6. Question 2 : I repeat this step upto $3$ times, untill I get at least one 6, what is the expected results of this specific process. And maybe, even at this step, you need more intermediate questions.  Excel will help you a lot in this exercice.

Comment: @Lourrran thank you, I will try

Comment: You can share you intermediate results (question 1, question 2), some people will confirm if you are ok or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game ends at a particular value of $N$ only if $KN$ rolls fail; the probability for that is $(1-p)^{KN}$. Otherwise, you end up at a lower value of $N$ with the number of attempts reset to $K$. The probabilities for reaching the possible lower values $n$ of $N$ are proportional to the binomial probabilities $\binom Nn(1-p)^np^{N-n}$, but we have to rescale those to add up to $1-(1-p)^{KN}$ instead of $1-(1-p)^N$, since the value $(1-p)^N$ for $n=N$ has been replaced by $(1-p)^{KN}$. Thus the transition probabilities from state $N$ to state $n$ are

$$
P(N\to n)=\begin{cases}(1-p)^{KN}&n=N\;,\\\frac{1-(1-p)^{KN}}{1-(1-p)^N}\binom Nn(1-p)^np^{N-n}&n\lt N\;.\end{cases}
$$

Since the number of dice in the winning pool is just the difference between the initial and final values of $N$, you can calculate the expectation and variance of the final value $M$ of $N$ instead, which yields slightly nicer expressions. Let $E_{iN}$ be the expected value of $M^i$ (where $i$ will be $1$ or $2$) starting with $N$ dice. Then with the above transition probabilities we have the recurrence

$$
E_{iN}=(1-p)^{KN}N^i+\frac{1-(1-p)^{KN}}{1-(1-p)^N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\binom Nn(1-p)^np^{N-n}E_{in}\;.
$$

The initial values are $E_{i0}=0$. I doubt that this can be solved in closed form. The first few values for your example with $K=3$, $p=\frac16$, and thus $1-p=\frac56$, are

$$
E_{11}=E_{21}=\left(\frac56\right)^3\;,
$$

\begin{eqnarray}
E_{12}
&=&
\left(\frac56\right)^6\cdot2+\frac{1-\left(\frac56\right)^6}{1-\left(\frac56\right)^2}\cdot2\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac16\cdot\left(\frac56\right)^3
\\
&=&
\frac{5138125}{5038848}
\\
&\approx&
1.02
\end{eqnarray}

and

\begin{eqnarray}
E_{22}
&=&
\left(\frac56\right)^6\cdot2^2+\frac{1-\left(\frac56\right)^6}{1-\left(\frac56\right)^2}\cdot2\cdot\frac56\cdot\frac16\cdot\left(\frac56\right)^3
\\
&=&
\frac{8513125}{5038848}
\\
&\approx&
1.69\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Thus, if we start with $N=2$ dice, we have

$$
E[M]=E_{12}\approx1.02
$$

and

\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{Var}[M]
&=&
E_{22}-E_{12}^2
\\
&=&
\frac{8513125}{5038848}-\left(\frac{5138125}{5038848}\right)^2
\\
&=&
\frac{16496014364375}{25389989167104}
\\
&\approx&
0.65
\;.
\end{eqnarray}